# is there anyway to recover close without saving file?

Tags: files

After lines of lines i -wrongly- closed the file without saving.Is there any way to rescue that lines(because of close without saving, it is not a file yet.)

Edit : I used Text Editor and it was a text file.I opened the new file to write.

Comment: Was this a text file? Ubuntu's 'Text Editor' saves a hidden file by default, and you would need to open Nautilus, go to the directory where the text file was, and press CTRL + H to see the hidden file.

Comment: You should at least specify what application you had it open in. And if you edited an existing file, or tried to create a new one. In the first case (editing an existing file), some editors do auto-save to a (temporary/backup) file, but chances are small you get your "abandoned lines" back.

Answer (score 2):

If you are real lucky, it might still be in memory:

```
sudo strings /dev/mem
```

Comment: I used this command but there aren't my text file.There are a lot of strings but i don't understand any of them.

Comment: Try adding ` | grep "some text"` to the end. Do it fast, and close all unneeded applications to preserve memory. In fact, you might want to dump all the memory to a text file by adding ` > savedMemory.txt` to the end of the command.

Comment: i changed the output to the file but there are a lot of irrelevant strings that i didn't write.

Comment: Of course, that is a dump of all your memory. Try searching that file to see if any of your lost text is in it.

Comment: I can not reach any string of my file now i accept that it totally lost.But here is my new question : Can i understand that command's output's meaning ?

Comment: Sure. Your memory contains all the information that went through your processor (very simplified explanation). That includes both text and binary. You can access all that information in `/dev/mem`. To do that, you would use `cat`. However, you can strip away the binary information and only view the text with `strings`. You could then search in the text with `grep` or redirect it to a file with `>`. If that's not clear, ask away!

Comment: You are so clear thanks :) i am not a dummy Linux user but i am not a Linux ninja also.So when i confuse about something i will ask here again.

Comment: Sure, I'll be here. You should also go back to your older askubuntu posts and accept the correct answers. That will raise your "accepted" ratio and encourage others to answer your questions.